# Prevent User from approving Pull Request

Tags: azure-devops

I have run into an issue where if my project managers are rushing, they sometimes will help move pull requests along by 'approving' them.  As we have set the branch policy to require at least 2 approvals (and the creator cannot be one), this can be a bit of a frustration.  I have moved the PMs into a new security group to isolate them from most options but I cannot find anything specific about Pull Requests.  Does this just follow under the Contribute option or is there a specific way I can block them from being able to approve pull requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have "Contribute to Pull Request" permissions, located under repo security settings. Remove that permission for the people you don't want to be approving PRs.

Comment: I do not see "Contribute to Pull Request" but in all fairness, things get changed all the time.  I add the group the PMs are into the branch security and then explicitly denied everything.

Comment: @JasonH Contribute to PR is located at the repo level, not the branch level.